# How to work with a CustomAppBar in flutter when the phone has a notch?

Tags: flutter

does anyone know how to use the SafeArea widget in a custom app bar. I am having a red overflow flex box appear on my custom app bar due to a notch in my emulator. I want to still show my custom app bar without the red overflow box in a way that looks presentable. When I tried surrounding my appbar in a safeArea widget I received an error in my Scaffold widget where I had placed my appBar. The code looked like this: `Scaffold( appBar: customAppBar(context))`. The error read: `The argument type 'SafeArea' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget'.` I believe that the Scaffold expects a PreferredSizeWidget but is receiving a safeArea widget instead. Please let me know if there are any other solutions out there other than using the SafeArea widget. Below is a photo of what my emulator looks like with the custom app bar and the red overflow box.

[image: emulator with red overflow flex box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want to make sure notches and punch holes don't get into your AppBar or UI, use the builder function from `MaterialApp` like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, child) => SafeArea(child: child),
      home: MyApp(),
    );
  }
```

Now every single Page/Screen will be safe from being cut on the top.